# Force expiring OpenStack Swift Tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, rackspace-cloud, openstack, cloudfiles, openstack-swift

Is there a way to force expire or revoke OpenStack Swift Tokens? I am looking some API method to do this.

Bing / Google search didn't return anything useful.

Comment: which auth middleware do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In swauth (after version 1.0.7), try to include `"X-Auth-New-Token: true"` in http header. And then swauth will issue a new token and revoke any old token.

Comment: what if I was on tempAuth ? actually wanted to invalidate the token to see what happens if I then try to upload some file to a temp-url (generated while token was invalid / expired)